# uwsgi connect() failed (111: Connection refused) - DOCKER - PYTHON

Tags: python, docker, http, uwsgi

I'm trying to do an infra with docker. I can't use flask or Django.

Here are my files, I tried lot of uwsgi parameters but I still have this error :

`connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.240.1, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:8080", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"`

I'm a student, I already read all the documentations, articles that I can, but I still don't know how to fix my problem.

Here are my different files.

[./default.conf]

```
upstream uwsgicluster {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location / {
        #try_files $uri @wsgi;
        uwsgi_pass uwsgicluster;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;

    }
}
```

[python/app.ini]

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file = run.py # The file containing the callable (app)
callable = python # The callable object itself
socket = :5000 #  The socket uwsgi will listen on
master = true
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
process = 2
```

[python/Dockerfile]

```
FROM python:3.6.5

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y uwsgi-plugin-python3
EXPOSE 5000 

COPY . .

RUN uwsgi --ini app.ini
```

[docker-compose.yml]

```
services:
  mysql_db:
    container_name: "mysql_db"
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
    volumes:
      - db_volume:/var/lib/mysql
    environment: # Set up mysql database name and password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: employees
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - app-db

  python3:
    restart: always
    build: ./python
    container_name: "python3"
    working_dir: "/root/"
    tty: true
    environment:
      - APP_NAME=DOCKER-TEST
    depends_on:
      - mysql_db
    networks:
      - app-front
      - app-db
    volumes:
      - ./python:/root
      - pycache_volume:/root/.cache
    links:
      - mysql_db

  front:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: "front"
    volumes:
      - ./front/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    networks:
      - app-front
    links:
      - python3


networks:
  app-front:
    driver: bridge
  app-db:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db_volume:
  pycache_volume:
```

Can you help me please ?
Thank you !

Comment: In the Nginx configuration, you need to use the Compose service name of the uWSGI service as a host name, and make sure the port matches; `server python3:5000`.  In the Python image you also need to make set `CMD uwsgi ...` so that becomes the main container process (not `RUN uwsgi ...`, which runs as part of the build and is then lost).

Comment: `links:` is an obsolete option and can be removed everywhere.  You should not need to manually specify `container_name:` or `working_dir:` either.  I'd recommend letting everything use the `default` network that Compose provides for you and deleting all of the `networks:` blocks in the entire file (which technically allows the Nginx reverse proxy to connect directly to the database, but you probably aren't too concerned about that).